# Strange problem with double in database mysql

Tags: mysql, double

I have some database table double:

```
 (somenumber float(11,2) DEFAULT '0.00' NOT NULL,)
```

If I try to save number "1.91" or "1.93" I get error like:

These fields of record 95 in table "tx_xxx_yyy" have not been saved correctly: somenumber! The values might have changed due to type casting of the database.

If I save muber "1.92" or "1.94" I do not get error.

Is this a MySql bug?

Thanks Martin

Comment: Everybody here has 'some strange problem'

Comment: [What every programmer should know about floating point](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~david/courses/cs552/S12/handouts/goldberg-floating-point.pdf)

Comment: Or do a google for `what every should know about floating point` and pick one you like the look of